# Duplicate columns with programatic names

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, purrr

I have annual data that I need to split into months. Operation is quite easy, as I just need to divide evenly the annual data over the months.

My first step would be to replicate the annual column 12 times, with already the appropriate column name (month). Next step would be to divide each column by 12.

I am stuck at the first step, as I am able to create the month columns, but just the first is populated, the rest are just NAs

See some code below with the Iris dataset

```
months <- paste(2019,seq(1,12,1), sep = "-")
map_df(months, ~
             iris %>% mutate(!!.x := Sepal.Length))
```

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species 2019-1 2019-2 2019-3 2019-4 2019-5 2019-6 2019-7 2019-8 2019-9 2019-10 2019-11 2019-12
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa    5.1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa    4.9     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa    4.7     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa    4.6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA
```

As you can see, for 2019-1 works fine (copies Sepal.Length), but the rest of the months are just NAs.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Much more straightforward also in `data.table`: `setDT(iris)[, (months) := Sepal.Length]` (though this probably won't work as `iris` is locked, you'd need to make a copy first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not empty. The problem is, your expression on the right hand side of `~` returns not a column, but a *tibble*. Check how many rows your result has:

```
map_df(months, ~ iris %>% mutate(!!.x := Sepal.Length)) %>% nrow
```

The result is 1800! This is because `map_df` is actually `map_dfr` in disguise, and it tries to bind the rows of your resulting data frames. First column therefore will be the Sepal.Width, then a bunch of NA's; next column – a bunch of NA's, then a bunch of values, then again a bunch of NA's... let us take only three dates and three rows from iris:

```
months <- paste(2019,seq(1,3,1), sep = "-")
map_df(months, ~ iris %>% slice(1:3) %>% mutate(!!.x := Sepal.Length) %>% select(!!.x))
```

The result is

```
  2019-1 2019-2 2019-3
1    5.1     NA     NA
2    4.9     NA     NA
3    4.7     NA     NA
4     NA    5.1     NA
5     NA    4.9     NA
6     NA    4.7     NA
7     NA     NA    5.1
8     NA     NA    4.9
9     NA     NA    4.7
```

To get what you want, you need to use `map_dfc` (binding by columns):

```
map_df(months, ~ iris %>% slice(1:3) %>% mutate(!!.x := Sepal.Length) %>% select(!!.x))
```

Result:

```
  2019-1 2019-2 2019-3
1    5.1    5.1    5.1
2    4.9    4.9    4.9
3    4.7    4.7    4.7
```

However, all that is too complicated. You can just do:

```
iris[,months] <- iris$Sepal.Width
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need this method when you can directly assign values to multiple columns.

```
df <- iris 
df[months] <- df$Sepal.Length

df[5:8]

#       Species 2019-1 2019-2 2019-3
#1       setosa    5.1    5.1    5.1
#2       setosa    4.9    4.9    4.9
#3       setosa    4.7    4.7    4.7
#4       setosa    4.6    4.6    4.6
#5       setosa    5.0    5.0    5.0
#6       setosa    5.4    5.4    5.4
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a big problem if you use a for loop to do that. Here, I provide an example of how I do that using {data.table}.

```
library(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)

months <- paste(2019, seq(1,12,1), sep = "-")

for(i in 1:12){

  iris[, (months[i]) := Sepal.Length]

}
```

As I am not too familiar with {dplyr}, I can give a similar equivalent, but there could be better ways out there to do it.

```
for(i in 1:12){

  iris <- mutate(iris, PlaceHolder = Sepal.Length)
  names(iris) <- gsub("PlaceHolder", months[i], names(iris))

}
```